# How to get a dataset value

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

New to VB.Net,

How to insert or select the dataset value.

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from table1", con)
    ada = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    ds = New DataSet
    ada.Fill(ds)
    cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from  '" & ds.Tables(0) & "'  ", con)
    mydatatable1.Load(dr3)
```

It was showing the error in `'" & ds.Tables(0) & "'`, I want to get the dataset value

Need VB.Net Code Help

Comment: @Gopal - are you trying to merge ds.Tables(0) (the datatable from the the first select statement) with mydatatable1? I don't know what the variable dr3 is...

Comment: @thedugas - I think it is more basic than that.  I think he just wants the data from table1 in DataTable format but doesn't realize that the Fill already does it.

Comment: @Mark Brittingham - Gotcha...

Comment: Gopal - thank you for choosing my answer as "the answer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a reasonable idea right up until you get to the point where you are trying to create a second SqlCommand.  That is, *once you do the Fill, you already have the data in a table.*  You wouldn't run another select - you've already done that. You'd just reference the table that you want to use in the dataset.

If you want a data table you would do something like this (for VB, see below):

```
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(CommandText, con);
    DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataset, "Table");  // "Table" is just a name, it can be anything.
    mydatatable1 = myDataset.Tables[0];  // Get the table
```

Now, if you don't need a DataTable, per se, but just want to read from the query, you'd use a SqlDataReader:

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, con);
 // One or more params
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", Value);
 SqlDataReader nwReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Then just read from the nwReader:

```
 while (nwReader.Read())
 {
     string field1Val = (string)nwReader["FieldName"];
     etc...
 }
```

---

**Update**:  I don't know VB but here is what I *think* it would look like:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from table1", con) 
ada = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) 
ds = New DataSet 
ada.Fill(ds) 
mydatatable1 = ds.Tables(0);
```

You may well be able to shorten this to get rid of the extra SqlCommand (assuming VB supports this SqlDataAdapater syntax like C#.

```
ada = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table1", con) 
ds = New DataSet 
ada.Fill(ds) 
mydatatable1 = ds.Tables(0);
```

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

you can use Microsoft Enterprise Library for making easy this process. this library is a powerful library for working with datasets.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public async Task<ResponseStatusViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            var responseStatusViewModel = new ResponseStatusViewModel();
            var connection = new SqlConnection(EmployeeConfig.EmployeeConnectionString);
            var command = new SqlCommand("usp_GetAllEmployee", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            try
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();
                var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                var dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataSet.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, new string[] { "Employee" });
                reader.Close();
                reader.Dispose();

                var employees = new List<EmployeeModel>();

                if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables["Employee"] != null)
                {
                    var employeeTable = dataSet.Tables["Employee"];

                    for (int i = 0; i < employeeTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var employeeRow = employeeTable.Rows[i];

                        employees.Add(new EmployeeModel
                        {
                            EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(employeeRow["EmployeeID"]),
                            EmployeeName = Convert.ToString(employeeRow["EmployeeName"]),
                            Address = Convert.ToString(employeeRow["Address"]),
                            GrossSalary = Convert.ToDouble(employeeRow["GrossSalary"]),
                            PF = Convert.ToDouble(employeeRow["PF"]),
                            TotalSalary = Convert.ToDouble(employeeRow["TotalSalary"])
                        });
                    }
                }
                responseStatusViewModel.Data = employees;
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

            return responseStatusViewModel;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is

cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from  '" & ds.Tables(0).**TableName** & "'  ", con)

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from table1", con)
ada = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
ada.Fill(ds)
cmd = New SqlCommand("Select * from  '" & ds.Tables(0).TableName & "'  ", con)
mydatatable1.Load(dr3)
```

Comment: -1 - Why would you ever do this?  The second cmd is just a rerun of the first and plays no functional role.  Also, even if there *were* some defense, you have an extra set of single quotes.

Comment: @Sachin. I used you query, It was showing error as "Incorrect syntax near Table".