# how to fill data set in C# using ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net, c#-3.0

**hello Friends**
can any body tell how to fill up a dataset in C# or a data table and what is dataadapter

Comment: Please go through this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter_members%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and post if you have any specific problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a dataset value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272915/how-to-get-a-dataset-value)

Answer (score 3):

[Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx)

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
string queryString = 
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

DataSet customers = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following below. I would suggest you do some more reading online to get a better understanding and maybe do a few examples.

```
// Assumes that customerConnection is a valid SqlConnection object.
// Assumes that orderConnection is a valid OleDbConnection object.
SqlDataAdapter custAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
  "SELECT * FROM dbo.Customers", customerConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter ordAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
  "SELECT * FROM Orders", orderConnection);

DataSet customerOrders = new DataSet();

custAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Customers");
ordAdapter.Fill(customerOrders, "Orders");

DataRelation relation = customerOrders.Relations.Add("CustOrders",
customerOrders.Tables["Customers"].Columns["CustomerID"],
customerOrders.Tables["Orders"].Columns["CustomerID"]);

foreach (DataRow pRow in customerOrders.Tables["Customers"].Rows)
{
   Console.WriteLine(pRow["CustomerID"]);
   foreach (DataRow cRow in pRow.GetChildRows(relation))
   Console.WriteLine("\t" + cRow["OrderID"]);
}
```

Taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @SUJEET, is that sarcasm I hear?